# Copying a tar ball from one server to another with Ansible

Tags: ansible, rsync

I am trying to copy a `tar.gz` archive file from the control host to a remote server using `Ansible`. Here is what the play looks like:

```
 # 0. Copy tar ball into directory.
    - name: copy java tar ball
      tags: copyJavaTarBall
      register: copyJavaTarBallOut
      copy: src={{ javaSrcLocation }} dest={{ javaDestLocation }}
      #shell: /bin/rsync -v -e "ssh -p {{ ansible_port }} -i {{ ansible_ssh_private_key_file }}" {{ javaSrcLocation }} sriram@{{ ansible_host }}:/home/sriram
      #synchronize:
      #  src: {{ javaSrcLocation }}
      #  dest: {{ javaDestLocation }}
      #  rsync_opts:
          #- "-e \" ssh -p {{ ansible_port }} -i {{ ansible_ssh_private_key_file }} \""
      #delegate_to: localhost
    - debug: var=copyJavaTarBallOut.stdout_lines
```

From among all these, the `copy` directive works only for simple files (text files etc.). Using a `tar.gz` archive results in the following error:

```
task path: /root/ansible/playbooks/javaSetup.yml:22
An exception occurred during task execution. The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 119, in run
    res = self._execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 490, in _execute
    result = self._handler.run(task_vars=variables)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/action/copy.py", line 153, in run
    source_full = self._loader.get_real_file(source_full)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/parsing/dataloader.py", line 402, in get_real_file
    if is_encrypted_file(f):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/parsing/vault/__init__.py", line 152, in is_encrypted_file
    b_vaulttext = to_bytes(to_text(vaulttext, encoding='ascii', errors='strict'), encoding='ascii', errors='strict')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/module_utils/_text.py", line 177, in to_text
    return obj.decode(encoding, errors)
MemoryError

fatal: [xx.yy.zz.aa]: FAILED! => {
    "failed": true,
    "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.",
    "stdout": ""
}
```

Using `rsync` either with `synchronize` or with the `shell` directive results in a stalled execution.

My question:
1. How do I copy the tar ball from the control host to the target server using Ansible?

**Update:
- Ansible is being invoked like so:
`ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES=1 ansible-playbook -vvvv -s javaSetup.yml --key-file=sshPvtKeys/pvtKeyFile.pem -c ssh --ask-sudo-pass -l appservers --tags copyJavaTarBall`
- The file size is 147M. The RAM size is roughly 1 GB.

Comment: "*`copy` directive works only for simple files*" -- what is a **simple file**?

Comment: `copy` module works also for tgz files. What are the values of `javaSrcLocation` and `javaDestLocation` variables? Can you also show the `ansible` or `ansible-playbook` command you used to run the task?

Comment: How large is your file? Copy module has troubles with files that can't fit into RAM.

Comment: @techraf: A **simple** file is a text file etc. There is no problem in copying such files.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov: Added more information. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to a memory issue when `Ansible` is used to copy files of large sizes. There is a [relevant discussion here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16391).

The steps I took to resolve this:
1. Used `split` to split the archive into multiple parts like so:
`split -b 10m jdk-7u79-linux-x64.tar.gz jdk-7u79-linux-x64.tar.gz.part-`
2. The play looks like so:

```
 # 0. Copy tar ball into directory.
    - name: copy java tar ball
      tags: copyJavaTarBall
      register: copyJavaTarBallOut
      copy: src={{ item }} dest={{ javaDestLocation }}
      with_fileglob:
        - "{{ javaSrcLocation }}/*"
    - debug: var=copyJavaTarBallOut.stdout_lines
```

Once it has been moved over to the remote server, it needs to be combined (with `cat`) and then unarchived. Cumbersome, but gets the job done.